# Why isn't this block executed with progress updates while the file is downloading via the Dropbox Sync API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox, dropbox-api

```
[tFile addObserver:self block:^() {
    NSLog(@"here");
}];
NSData * tData = [tFile readData:&tError];
```

I have an existing observer functioning perfectly fine:

```
[tFilesystem addObserver:self forPathAndDescendants:[DBPath root] block:^() {}];
```

---

EDIT

It appears the block isn't being called in the example notes app either.

```
[_file addObserver:self block:^() { [self reload]; }];
```

This should reload the file after editing a file on the desktop and saving. It doesn't.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?